Is there a built-in way to show local git refs matching a prefix?
When I do git ls-remote, I can specify a wildcard pattern to match references with a given suffix.
git ls-remote origin refs/xxx/*

# Output
907b308167f0880fb2a5c0e1614bb0c7620f9dc3   refs/xxx/foobar

However, there no obvious equivalent option in git show-ref.
Running git show-ref refs/xxx/* returns nothing even when a ref called refs/xxx/foobar exists.
I could just pipe to awk or grep, but is there is a built-in way to filter by ref prefix locally?

git for-each-ref 'refs/xxx/*'

You could clone the repo a second time. The second clone's remote would then be the one you currently have, so you can use ls-remote. Just sayin'.

I think for-each-ref was what I was looking for.
Cloning the repo a second time is a creative solution indeed! :)

Also: paths are valid for repo specifiers, try git ls-remote . refs/xxx/*

@jthill That is very beautiful!
